# Can someone please help me with this solution? Beginner here. Python

Tags: python

You have a list of elements between 0 and 99. Write a function to count the number of elements in groups 0-9, 10-19, 20-29 and so on.

Your function should return a list of numbers separated by a space with counts of the number in each group. For example index 0 will have count for 0-10, index 1 for 10-20 and so on.

For example list 1 5 99 98 7 will return 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible answer:

```
list = [1, 5, 99, 98, 7]
result = [0] * 10

for x in list:
        result [x//10] += 1

print (result)
```